# Cross referencing with extended classes in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I've found a strange bug.

If you have two classes in different files, and for example class **B** extends class **A**, and class **A** has a variable typed **B**, TypeScript compiles in wrong order with --out main.js command (when you compile whole project into one file).
Wrond order results that javascript throws an error: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined* 
This is because class **B** is earlier in the code than **A**, and it want to use it.

Here is the simpliest example:

**A.ts**

```
///<reference path='B.ts'/>

class A
{
    public b: B;

    constructor()
    {
    }

    init()
    {
        this.b=new B();
    }
}
```

**B.ts**

```
///<reference path='A.ts'/>
class B extends A
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();
    }
}
```

**app.ts**

```
///<reference path='A.ts'/>
var a: A=new A();
a.init();
```

**Generated main.js**

```
var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};
var B = (function (_super) {
    __extends(B, _super);
    function B() {
        _super.call(this);
    }
    return B;
})(A);
var A = (function () {
    function A() {
    }
    A.prototype.init = function () {
        this.b = new B();
    };
    return A;
})();
var a = new A();
a.init();
//@ sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
```

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your circular dependencies. If you want to substitute the classes then the dependencies really ought to be in one direction. Here is an example:

```
class A {
    constructor(public b: A)
    {
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    constructor()
    {
        super(this);
    }
}

var a = new A(new B());
var b = new B();
```

Now Your "b.ts" file only needs to depend on the "a.ts" file - not the other way around. Because B extends A, you can pass in an instance of B when you create a new A. Because the dependency is one-directional, TypeScript now has a chance of compiling things in the right order.

[image: Here is a picture to show the dependency issue:enter image description here]

Comment: This could work, but A must really have to know about class B, because in my real code it will uses it's special properties, so i can't use this method. In javascript if I change the order manually after compiling it works like a charm.

Comment: I've found two workarounds to this problem, but none of it is too good: user Interface instead of the exact class, or you can use type **any** but this is not so good....

Comment: Really, you need to kill the dependency issue. Either A can't depend on B, or vice versa. It may be that you need to move away from inheritance and use delegation instead.

Comment: In other OOP languages such dependencies allowed, but anyway the worst thing is that compiler can create js code with fatal errors... Thank You anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `export` statement on the declared typescript module or class or interface, then you can `import` the desired function, class or whatever. Typescript is throwing an error because the variable you are trying to reference does not exist.

For example:

```
module API {
    export class Main {
        public name: string;
        public interest: string;

        constructor() {
            this.name = "Someone";
            this.interest = "web technology";
        }

        puts() {
            console.log(this.name, " like", this.interest);
        }
    }
}
```

..and then you can call the desired function.

```
import API;
var c = new API.Main();
```

Comment: For this question, the classes are not wrapped in an internal module, so the `export` keyword isn't required.