# Cross-referencing between parent and child class

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to build a fluent-API library in typescript and I have 2 classes, in separate files, that reference each other as follows:

**a.ts**

```
import * as b from "./b"

export abstract class A {
    static create(n: number) : A {
        return new b.B(n);
    }
}
```

**b.ts**

```
import * as a from "./a"

export class B extends a.A {
    constructor(n: number) { 
        super();
    }
}
```

My application is:

**app.ts**

```
import * as a from "./a"

a.A.create(1);
```

I've set up Visual Studio Code to run this on Node locally but I get "Cannot read prototype on undefined" on this line of the generated b.js:

```
d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
```

Is there a way to resolve this cyclic initialization dependency?

** Edit **

The only workaround I found is to put B in the same file as A (B doesn't have to be exported anyway).

My problem is then that there will be C, D, E, etc. classes, which makes A.ts very long and hard to maintain.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156414/cross-referencing-with-extended-classes-in-typescipt

Comment: Yeah, saw that, but its an old question and the answer was unhelpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to manually specify the order of imports in `app.ts`:

```
import "./b";  // Manually import `b.ts` before `a.ts` 
import * as a from "./a";

a.A.create(1);
```

I'm unsure if the problem would be solved with future version of Node.js that will implement the ES6 syntax of `import` / `export`. Maybe it is a limitation of the inheritance mechanism of ES6 classes.