# Typescript Parent Class type guard to Child Classes

Tags: typescript, inheritance, types, parent-child, instanceof

I have a an abstract class `FooObject`. Only two children ever inherit `FooObject`, lets call them `ThisFooObject` and `ThatFooObject`.

I'm looking for a **performant** way to turn a FooObject into whichever child it is. In this case, that means not using `instanceof` - which [performs](https://jsperf.com/instanceof-performance/2) at <10% the speed of a boolean lookup.

The way I've investigated is something like this:

## FooObject.ts

```
import ThisObject from "./ThisObject";
import ThatObject from "./ThatObject";

abstract class FooObject {

  isThisObject() : this is ThisFooObject {
    // Either check for ThisFooObject properties, or override this
    // in the ThisFooObject class to always return true.
    return duckTypingTest();
  }

  // ditto here
  isThatObject() : this is ThatFooObject {}
}
```

I understand that this is not pretty. It's not a scalable approach if I have more children of FooObject - and it requires the parent to know about the children in a kinda encapsulation breaking way. But in my specific case, I'm willing to put up with this if it avoids me having to do 'instanceof'.

On the bright side, when I have a reference to a FooObject, and I want to something when it's a ThatFooObject, I can do something like:

```
fooObjects.forEach( foo => {
  // Foo currently typed as a FooObject
  if(foo.isThatObject()){
    // Foo now typed as a ThatFooObject
    foo.magic+=10
  }
});
```

This is all works - with one little caveat - I have to [be careful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37067411/cross-referencing-between-parent-and-child-class) to get the import order correct. IE, in my `main.ts` entry point, do something like

```
import 'ThatFooObject';
import 'FooObject';
```

But other than that, I'm fairly well pleased with this pattern. The issue comes when I try this with **more than one** child. I start to get issues with circular dependencies throwing things off, and errors like `class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null`.

I can't figure out how to make this work. Am I just barking up the wrong tree, and I should do this a much simpler way?

Comment: If you're getting errors like that from import order then your loader is not adhering to the spec.

Comment: Can't reproduce this problem, always gets imported in the correct order no matter in which order I import the three files. Maybe you can provide a full example which results in circular dependencies or wrong import order? 
One ugly solution (For whatever problem you actually have) may be moving the import statements to the bottom of the FooObject.ts to enforce that these other files are imported AFTER the FooObject class is created.

Answer (score 6):

How about something like this, which doesn't require the classes to know about each other:

The plan is to give each concrete constructor a string property called `typeId` which we will use to distinguish among subclasses.  Here's the shape of a `FooObject` constructor:

```
interface FooObjectConstructor<T extends FooObject> {
  new(...args: any[]): T
  typeId: string;
}
```

Now we can define the abstract `FooObject` class:

```
abstract class FooObject {

  // note 1
  // abstract static readonly typeId: string;  

  // note 2
  readonly typeId = (this.constructor as FooObjectConstructor<this>).typeId; 

  // note 3
  instanceOf<T extends FooObject>(ctor: FooObjectConstructor<T>): this is T {
    return this.typeId === ctor.typeId
  }
}
```

1. TypeScript doesn't allow abstract static properties, so I can't say `abstract static typeId` and have the compiler warn me if my subclass doesn't implement it.  So we just have to remember to do it ourselves.
2. We will copy the static `typeId` to each instance upon creation, so that the instance can access `this.typeId` instead of `this.constructor.typeId`.  I'm not sure if this helps performance much, but you can leave this out and replace references to `this.typeId` with `this.constructor.typeId` everywhere if you want.
3. The `instanceOf` method is generic and accepts a `FooObject` constructor, and compares the `typeId` of the current object to the `typeId` of the passed-in constructor.  The fact that it's generic is helping us keep the parent class from needing to know about each subclass, and avoiding the web of craziness you're running into above.

Okay, so let's create those concrete subclasses.  We must remember to set the static `typeId` to a unique value:

```
class ThisObject extends FooObject {
  static readonly typeId = "ThisObject" // don't forget this
  thisMethod() {
    console.log("This!")
  }      
}

class ThatObject extends FooObject {
  static readonly typeId = "ThatObject" // don't forget this
  thatMethod() {
    console.log("That!")
  }
}
```

Okay, time to test it!

```
declare const someFooObject: FooObject;

if (someFooObject.instanceOf(ThisObject)) {
  someFooObject.thisMethod();
} else if (someFooObject.instanceOf(ThatObject)) {
  someFooObject.thatMethod();
} else {
  // some other type of FooObject, I guess
  console.log("I wasn't expecting that");
}
```

All the code above produces no compilation warnings for me, and it [works for me at runtime](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#src=interface%20FooObjectConstructor%3CT%20extends%20FooObject%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20new%28...args%3A%20any%5B%5D%29%3A%20T%0D%0A%20typeId%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aabstract%20class%20FooObject%20%7B%0D%0A%20readonly%20typeId%20%3D%20%28this.constructor%20as%20FooObjectConstructor%3Cthis%3E%29.typeId%3B%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20instanceOf%3CT%20extends%20FooObject%3E%28ctor%3A%20FooObjectConstructor%3CT%3E%29%3A%20this%20is%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20return%20this.typeId%20%3D%3D%3D%20ctor.typeId%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20ThisObject%20extends%20FooObject%20%7B%0D%0A%20static%20readonly%20typeId%20%3D%20%22ThisObject%22%20%2F%2F%20don%27t%20forget%20this%0D%0A%20thisMethod%28%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20console.log%28%22This%21%22%29%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20ThatObject%20extends%20FooObject%20%7B%0D%0A%20static%20readonly%20typeId%20%3D%20%22ThatObject%22%20%2F%2F%20don%27t%20forget%20this%0D%0A%20thatMethod%28%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20console.log%28%22That%21%22%29%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20someFooObject%3A%20FooObject%20%3D%20Math.random%28%29%20%3C%200.5%20%3F%20new%20ThisObject%28%29%20%3A%20new%20ThatObject%28%29%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20%28someFooObject.instanceOf%28ThisObject%29%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20someFooObject.thisMethod%28%29%3B%0D%0A%7D%20else%20if%20%28someFooObject.instanceOf%28ThatObject%29%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20someFooObject.thatMethod%28%29%3B%0D%0A%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20console.log%28%22I%20wasn%27t%20expecting%20that%22%29%0D%0A%7D).

Hope that helps; good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've found ***a*** solution - but it's not great.

See that dance I had to do in main.ts of forcing the correct import order by importing the child class before the parent:

## main.ts

```
import "./ThisFooObject"; // <-- forces correct order.
import FooObject from "./FooObject";
```

I have to double down and do that in all the children, for all the other ones. Since I only have two, this isn't a huge issue, but this scales exponentially with more subclasses. EG:

## ThisFooObject.ts

```
import "./ThatFooObject" <-- Forces correct order despite not being used
import "./FooObject"
```

## ThatFooObject.ts

```
import "./ThisFooObject" <-- Forces correct order despite not being used
import "./FooObject"
```